# how to get the selected item value from select list and process it

Tags: apex, visualforce, selectlist, selectoption

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="Ctrl_Event_Registration">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock title="Event Registration">
<apex:pageBlockButtons >
<apex:commandButton action="{!onclick}" value="Mark Attended" reRender="out"/>
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select the Event Name">    
<apex:selectList value="{!events}" multiselect="false">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!selectEvent}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>  
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Select the Contact Name">    
<apex:selectList value="{!contacts}" multiselect="false">
<apex:selectOptions value="{!selectContact}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>            
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Ctrl_Event_Registration {

public String contacts{get;set;}
public String events{get;set;}

public Event_Registration__c eve{get;set;}
List<SelectOption> eventOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
 List<SelectOption> contactOptions = new List<SelectOption>();

public Ctrl_Event_Registration ()
{

}
public PageReference onclick()
{
    try{
    system.debug('eveeeeeeeeeeee...........' + eve );
        if(eve != null)
        {
            for(Event_Registration__c register : [SELECT id,Event__c,Name ,Attended_Event__c,Contact__c 
                                                    FROM Event_Registration__c])
                                                    {
                                                        register.Attended_Event__c = true;
                                                    }
            update eve;
        }
    }catch(DMLException ex)
    {
        ApexPages.addMessages(ex);  
    }
    return null;
}

public List<SelectOption> getSelectEvent() {

    eventOptions.add(new SelectOption('','--None--'));
    for(Event__c eve : [SELECT id,name From Event__c WHERE Event_Start_Date__c > Today])   
    {
     eventOptions.add(new SelectOption(eve.id,eve.Name));   
    }  

    return eventOptions;
}

public List<SelectOption> getSelectContact(){

    contactOptions .add(new SelectOption('','-None-'));       
    for(Event_Registration__c  ev : [SELECT id,Contact__r.Name from Event_Registration__c where Event__r.Event_Start_Date__c > Today and Attended_Event__c =false])
    {
        contactOptions .add(new selectOption(ev.id,ev.Contact__r.Name));
    }
    return contactOptions ;
}

public List<SelectOption> options {get; set;}
    public string Choice {get; set;}
    public string choiceName {get{
        for (SelectOption so : Options){
            if (so.getValue() == choice){
                return so.getLabel();
            }
        }
        return null;    
    }}
    public String getChoice() {
        return Choice;
    }  
public String getEvents()
{
    return events;
    }

public void setEvents(String events)
{
    this.events = events;
}
}
```

I want the id of the selected item from the picklist and query it in onclick function.

Comment: Some help me with that long time ago [Check this out](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50704/accessing-picklist-values-from-controller)

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the selected values from the Selectlist in your controller as you already have a setter and getter for the strings events and contacts.

Basically calling the onclick method should show you the record id values for the events and contacts selected:

```
public PageReference onclick() {
    system.debug('events...........' + events);
    system.debug('contacts.........' + contacts);
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [apex ActionFunction](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) to accomplish this.  Call the name of the action function for the Select List onChange method.  Then use the action function to reference the desired method in your controller.